# How to make VS2017 ignore a specific compiler's keyword?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I use Visual Studio 2017 with ReSharper 2017.2 as the code editor for an embedded project. I managed to configure all but one thing:

[image: snippet screenshot]

How do I make VS/R# ignore that specific keyword, `_Interrupt1`? (this error causes other side effects).

I tried to add it as a preprocessor definition (Project's properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions), but it doesn't help.

Comment: It is in [the FM](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReSharper_by_Language_CPP.html), use the `__RESHARPER__` macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about R#, but in VS you could try to define globally:

```
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
#define _Interrupt1
#endif
```

to hide `_Interrupt1` from Intellisense parsing.

For completeness, thanks to @Hans Passant, use `__RESHARPER__` for RS

Comment: This solution forces me to enter specific code just for the editor. Is there no way around it?

Comment: @Tar Only thing is to add it on project level, so code is not touched. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx